# Open plain text with default applicaiton

Tags: gnome

The the default shell editor could be set as

```
$ echo $EDITOR
emacsclient -nw -s 'coding'
```

How could configure to open files in nautils with the above approach

[image]

Even though the `emacs terminal` can be select, it start fresh instead of taking  advantage of the running emacs server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications listed in the "Open with" tab correspond with .desktop files of the application. These .desktop files inform your desktop environment how the application should be started, and are used to populate your application menu.

In this .desktop file, there is a line starting with "Exec=" where the command to launch the application is defined. Many programs can automatically open a file upon launching when you provide the file name on the command line. In .desktop files, the command usually contains a placeholder %U that serves that purpose. %U is replaced with the name of the currently selected file when you launch a file by double-clicking on it in the file manager.

Thus, find the .desktop file corresponding with your application. Make sure that the parameter %U figures correctly in the command line defined after "Exec=". Because in your case the application is a terminal application, make sure the .desktop file also includes a line `Terminal=true`.

If everything is correctly configured, double-clicking a file will open your editor in a terminal window, with the selected file opened.